# LibGDX search for file types in local file system

Tags: libgdx, scene2d, file

I'm building a system that allows users to upload files to LibGDX's local directory to play them in the game. How can I search recursively through the local file system for a specific file type and return all returned files?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Files.walk()` along with `filter()`. Thus if you wanted to get all PNG images, then you could do:

```
Path path = Paths.get(Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath());

try {
    List<Path> files = Files.walk(path)
        .filter(filePath -> !Files.isDirectory(filePath) && 
                            filePath.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".png"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

The example starts searching from `Gdx.files.getLocalStoragePath()` continuously searching all subdirectories for any file ending with `.png`.

It might be important to include `!Files.isDirectory(filePath)` as technically someone could name a directory `test.png`.

Comment: I get this error:
Usage of API Document @ 1.7
This inspection finds all usages of methods that have @since in their documentation.
This may be useful for development for development under newer SDKs

Comment: It's telling your that it knows what it is, but that it comes from 1.7. Sounds like you're not using at least 1.7.

Comment: Does that mean that I need to update java itself or in android studio?

Comment: [You just need to change the language level.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637179/how-to-set-source-1-7-in-android-studio-and-gradle) Whether you need to update anything depends on what you currently have.

Comment: I've updated it to jdk1.8.0_111 and it still gives errors.

Comment: [Try going through and reading this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development/23318269#23318269)